# OOP Pattern with methods calling Repositories

Tags: php, oop, symfony, doctrine, repository-pattern

I have a class DashboardService (defined as a service in symfony2), i use it to call some methods to get results (just queries) from some repositories  and display data.

```
class DashboardService {

/**
 * @var EntityManager 
 */
private $em;

public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
    $this->em = $em;
}

public function getTotalActiveCampaignsByMonth($month) {

    $campaigns = $this->em->getRepository("WMAdminBundle:Campaign")->countAllActiveCampaignsByMonth($month);

    return $campaigns;
}

public function getTotalContactsByMonth($month) {

    $contacts = $this->em->getRepository("WMAdminBundle:Contact")->countAllContactsSentByMonth($month);

    return $contacts;
}

public function getTotalCAByMonth($month) {
    $ca = $this->em->getRepository("WMAdminBundle:ContactCampaign")->getAllCAByMonth($month);

    return $ca;
}

public function getTop10RentabilityCampaigns() {
    $campaigns = $this->em->getRepository("WMAdminBundle:Campaign")->findAllTop10Rentability();

    return $campaigns;
}

public function getTop10ContactCampaigns() {
    $campaigns = $this->em->getRepository("WMAdminBundle:Campaign")->findAllTop10Contacts();

    return $campaigns;
}

}
```

Is this class an OOP pattern or something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's like a basic application service in a typical layered architecture.

> **Application Services** : Used by external consumers to talk to your system (think Web Services). If consumers need access to CRUD operations, they would be exposed here.

Comment: Ok so you do you think it's a good practice to use this class in my controller like this : 
`$this->get("dashboard")-> getTotalActiveCampaignsByMonth($month);`
 or it's preferable to do directly in controller : 
`$this->em->getRepository("WMAdminBundle:Campaign")->countAllActiveCampaignsByMonth($month);` 
and remove my service class ?

Comment: it's not a good idea to inject (or locate) your repositories in your controllers and use them. Because not all your repository calls are just fetching data. In most of the command calls you need to validate and check some business rules and then call a repository method. That's what you should do in your application service.

Comment: Ok but in my case there is no business logic inside my Campaign Service, only calls to repositories just doing queries.

Comment: In this case you can call your repositories in controllers, but i don't recommend it. Because controllers are meant to be a part of "Interface" layer and should only call services. tight coupling your repositories to your controllers may cause you lots of changes in future. (consider a query that used in different controllers, now you wanna change it to call two repository method. you should change it in all controllers). even in CQRS pattern there is always a facade service that abstracts the query model : [CQRS pattern diagram](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/555855/CQRS.jpg)